# Android device not found (dont know why)

Tags: android, eclipse, device

I formatted my laptop and installed eclipse again an other stuff. When I run the application, I get this message:

> Installation error: Unknown failure Please check logcat output for
>   more details. Failed to install ****.apk on device 'emulator-5554':
>   device not found com.android.ddmlib.InstallException: device not found
>   Launch canceled!

Does anyone know why?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try with this from the command line:

```
adb kill-server
adb start-server
```

Also, you should migrate to [Android Studio](https://developer.android.com/sdk/index.html), there is a better support and the Eclipse ADT plugin is [no longer supported by Google](http://android-developers.blogspot.mx/2015/06/an-update-on-eclipse-android-developer.html).

Comment: The adb utility is available here {android_sdk_path}\platform-tools

Comment: Ok, I know android sdk managment\platform-tools .. but not the path, where is it?

Comment: Well...I think you need  to install everything again from scratch. Give it a try to Android Studio, you'll like it...!! :)

Comment: The application is ready to load to play.google, i just need to fix this :/

Comment: If adb is not where it used to then something should be missing/corrupted, adb must be there as part of the Android SDK. In any case try to re-install the Android SDK.

Comment: I found the adb.exe and ran the kill and start, I got a new error :/ Failed to install ***.apk on device 'emulator-5554': timeout
 Launch canceled!

Comment: Try with: adb devices, there should be listed your emulator